# How can I smoothly transition a countdown (progress) bar in Firefox?

Tags: css, progress-bar, countdown

Hoping someone might be able to clear up some confusion regarding "progress" and -moz-transition.

```
progress {
width: 40%;
-webkit-transition: width 2500ms ease-out;
-moz-transition: width 2500ms ease-out;
-o-transition: width 2500ms ease-out;
transition: width 2500ms ease-out;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
transition: width 2500ms ease-out;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
transition: width 2500ms ease-out;
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
transition: width 2500ms ease-out;
}
```

Basically, I am coding a countdown timer that also uses a progress bar.
https://jsfiddle.net/TBylicky/1ndzc0x5/

The issue is that while I can get smooth progress bar transition in Chrome, I cannot for the life of me, figure out why it isn't smooth with Firefox.

Comment: your forget the `-moz-progress-value` ?

Comment: Temani, adding `-moz-progress-value` does not seem to change anything.